# How to print TimeWindowedKStream and KTable in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka process that takes a topic as input and writes timed window to the output topic.. the following code is being used. I would like to print TimeWindowedKStream(groupedStream) and KTable(aggregatedTable) and see the output for some debugging purposes..

```
    String intopic = input_topic;
    Long window = 60;
    String outtopic = output_topic;
    
    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

    Properties property = new Properties();
    property.put("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
    property.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
    property.put("application.id", "sliding-window-min-bar");
    property.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, stringSerde.getClass().getName());
    property.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, stringSerde.getClass().getName());

    Duration windowSizeMs = Duration.ofMinutes(window);

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    
    System.out.println(intopic);

    KStream<String, String> equitybar = builder.stream(intopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
    
    System.out.println(equitybar);
    
    equitybar.print(Printed.toSysOut());

    // convert string of csv to a double on the mean value
    KStream<String, String> transformedbar = equitybar
            .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, value.substring(1,value.length()-2).split(",")[2]));

    System.out.println(transformedbar);

    transformedbar.print(Printed.toSysOut());
    
    // group by equity and sliding window
    
    System.out.println(windowSizeMs);
    System.out.println(TimeWindows.of(windowSizeMs).advanceBy(advanceMs));
    
    TimeWindowedKStream<String, String> groupedStream = transformedbar.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowSizeMs).advanceBy(advanceMs));

    System.out.println(groupedStream);
    KTable<Windowed<String>, String> aggregatedTable = groupedStream.aggregate(
            () -> "|",
            (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + newValue.trim() + "|")      ;
```

I tried to print it using the the print command that is used for Kafka streams -  groupedStream.print(Printed.toSysOut()); - but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`KGroupedStream` and `TimeWindowedKStream` are "just" helper classes to allow the DSL to present a fluent API to chain operator without too many overloads on a single class.

In the DSL, there are only two main abstractions, `KStream` and `KTable` that are actual first-class data-containers. Thus, it's not possible what you want to do.